# How to convert a result of one object to string object

Tags: java

I am new to java. There is a method which return a value of type xxx.

```
   public Cost getTotalCost() {
    return getCost();
}
```

I want to convert the getCost() to type string. How do I do it?

Comment: `getCost().toString()` or `String.valueOf(getCost())`

Comment: `String.valueOf(int)` could work nicely.

Comment: What does the `Cost` class look like? Also, `@Override public String toString()` is a lifesaver.

Comment: None of these answers make any sense without knowing what a `Cost` is or what you want the output to actually look like.

Comment: @Legend assuming `Cost` is an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most universal way is:

```
 String.valueOf(getCost());
```

This will handle nulls, or invoke the `.toString()` method of the object.

It would be best to implement the `.toString()` method for your `Cost` class.

---

Note that it is considered poor practice to programmatically rely on the `toString()` method - it should be for human eyes only and not be locked into a specific implementation.